# Is it possible to create a queue triggered azure function with queue name pattern or for multiple queues?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am developing a queue triggered azure function. Also I am very new to it. Following is the configuration of my "function.json" file:

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myQueueItem",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "testqueue-1",
      "connection": "MyQueueTriggeredConnectionString"
    }
  ]
}
```

My function is working fine. It is triggered for all entries in "testqueue-1" queue.

now I have few questions:

1. Can I give multiple queue name in "queueName" parameter?
2. Can I give some naming pattern in "queueName" paramener. Like we can give pattern in "path" parameter in blob triggered function: "path": "input/{name1}~123~{name2}"
3. If I do 10 entries in my queue. Will all entries execute simultaneously? or one by one? If it is simultaneously, How can I make it one by one?

Also if possible. please share some useful links that can help me to understand queue triggered azure in better way.

Thanks,

Comment: Please be a bit more specific, since this is a very broad post. Also, I believe most of your questions are relatively easy to [search for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-queue-triggered-function) or find on [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/808). Refer to [ask].

Comment: @rickvdbosch Thanks for showing interest to help me. My specific question is : Can I bind my single queue triggered azure function to multiple queues? if Yes the how?

Comment: By default: no you cannot. You can, however, have multiple functions _in the same class_ all trigger on different queuenames, but call the same logic to handle the messages.

Comment: I wonder why you would want an azure function to be triggered by multiple queues. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @PeterBons, I have separate queue for each of my customers. But I want to execute one common logic on all queues. That is why I want a queue triggered function that can handle multiple queues

Answer (score 3):

Although the question is not super elaborate I will try to answer what I think you want to know;

**Can I give multiple queue name in "queueName" parameter?**
No. And it really doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to have for example two queues trigger the same function. Why not just define a parameter on your queue message to define the client? For example a jSON? Otherwise you will have to be creating queues for each client. What a nightmare.

**Can I give some naming pattern in "queueName" parameter. Like we can give pattern in "path" parameter in blob triggered function: "path": "input/{name1}~123~{name2}"**
No. Once again that's not what queue binding is for. Pass parameters on the message.

**If I do 10 entries in my queue. Will all entries execute simultaneously? or one by one? If it is simultaneously, How can I make it one by one?**
You can define this on your host.json file. Check the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json

If you want to make it one by one you can define singleton or, although still not fully supported, set WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT to 1 in you application settings.